# SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, python-3.5

I don't know how I can use any elements to get clicked on this submit button. 
I've tried it using `xpath`.,

```
web.find_elements_by_xpath('\\input value="submit" type="submit"').click()
```

but I get the error metioned in the title.

I searched and I couldn't find any solution.
Here's the inspected element by the browser:
[image: Submit button type value]

Comment: Looks like your slashes should lean to the right. See [this info](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) for various examples and other info.

Comment: That doesn't look like any XPath I've ever seen... you probably should read some basic XPath tutorials and other questions on SO, etc. and edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you pass to `find_elements_by_xpath()` doesn't looks like `XPath`. Also `find_elements_by_xpath()` should return you a list which doesn't have an attribute `click()`. Try to use below instead:

```
web.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="submit" and @type="submit"]').click()
```